# Python OLS calculation

Tags: python

Is there any good library to calculate linear least squares OLS (Ordinary Least Squares) in python?

Thanks.

Edit:

Thanks for the SciKits and Scipy. 
@ars: Can X be a matrix? An example:

```
y(1) = a(1)*x(11) + a(2)*x(12) + a(3)*x(13)
y(2) = a(1)*x(21) + a(2)*x(22) + a(3)*x(23)
...........................................
y(n) = a(1)*x(n1) = a(2)*x(n2) + a(3)*x(n3)
```

Then how do I pass the parameters for Y and X matrices in your example?

Also, I don't have much background in algebra, I would appreciate if you guys can let me know a good tutorial for that kind of problems.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 9):

Try the [statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/) package.  Here's a quick example:

```
import pylab
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm

x = np.arange(-10, 10)
y = 2*x + np.random.normal(size=len(x))

# model matrix with intercept
X = sm.add_constant(x)

# least squares fit
model = sm.OLS(y, X)
fit = model.fit()

print fit.summary()

pylab.scatter(x, y)
pylab.plot(x, fit.fittedvalues)
```

*Update*  In response to the updated question, yes it works with matrices.  Note that the code above has the `x` data in array form, but we build a matrix `X` (capital X) to pass to `OLS`.  The `add_constant` function simply builds the matrix with a first column initialized to ones for the intercept.  In your case, you would simply pass your `X` matrix without needing that intermediate step and it would work.

Comment: (+1) Any chance to see you back on stats.stackexchange.com?

Comment: @chl: Definitely -- got busy with some programming work and check in here occasionally, but must find my way back to stats.SE soon.  Good to hear from you.  :)

Answer (score 4):

Have you looked at SciPy? I don't know if it does that, but I would imagine it will.

Comment: +1: Scipy is *the* de facto standard for this kind of computation and many others.

Comment: Don't discount the [scikits](http://scikits.appspot.com/) ecosystem of packages being built around SciPy -- of which [statsmodels](http://scikits.appspot.com/statsmodels) is one.